# AttributeError: function 'GetWindowLongPtrW' not found

Tags: python-2.7, ctypes

This is on windows x64 for python 2.7

```
from ctypes import *
user32 = windll.user32
GWL_STYLE = -16
style = c_long(0)
pstyle = pointer(style)
pstyle = user32.GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWL_STYLE)
```

Am getting the error in title.  Is this function not supported in ctypes? I'm using other user32 functions in this pyscript without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `GetWindowLongW` in a 32-bit process, and `GetWindowLongPtrW` in a 64-bit process.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on 64 bit windows, using GetWindowLongPtr, and getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. I had a 32 bit version of python installed on 64 bit windows 7. Above code worked after installing Python 2.7.8 x64.